# Why i cant save this request in state Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import api from '../../services/api';
import axios from 'axios';


export default function Body() {

    const[resWorld, setResWorld] = useState([]);
    const[ranking, setRanking] = useState([]);
  
 
    useEffect(() =>{

        axios.get('https://api.covid19api.com/world/total').then(res => setResWorld(res.data))
        
    },[]);

    useEffect(() =>{

        axios.get('https://covid19-brazil-api.now.sh/api/report/v1/countries')
        .then(res => setRanking(res.data))
        
    },[])
```

First sorry for my english...
I have to request this two differents API and save in these states... the problem is the second(
Apparently the response is different, is a object, and i dont know how to save in the ranking state

Answer (score 1):

Since the response for both is different. According to your answer it looks like you are able to store data for resWorld but not ranking. If this is so, you can do like below

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import api from '../../services/api';
import axios from 'axios';


export default function Body() {

   const[resWorld, setResWorld] = useState({});
const[ranking, setRanking] = useState([]);


useEffect(() =>{

    axios.get('https://api.covid19api.com/world/total').then(res => setResWorld(res.data))
    
},[]);

useEffect(() =>{

    axios.get('https://covid19-brazil-api.now.sh/api/report/v1/countries')
    .then(res => setRanking(res.data.data)) // HERE IS THE CHANGE
    
},[])


useEffect(() => {
console.log('Ranking', ranking)
    // do the operation here which you want after Ranking state is updated
}, [ranking]);


return (<div> {JSON.stringify(ranking)} </div>)
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but when i do console.log(ranking) it gives a empty array

Comment: I ran the code at my end and it works perfectly. Could you please tell where are you putting console.log

Comment: Please give the complete function

Comment: I have put console.log also, you can try and execute the code in my answer as is and let me know if you face any problem

Comment: You won't be able to see the changes to ranking state just after doiing setRanking, since setRanking is an asynchronous function. If you want to carry out any operation on change of state for ranking, than I have updated my answer and I have put one new effect where you can do that

Comment: Why the console.log is repeating the response.data?

Comment: Its repeating because we have not put it inside any hook. It will repeat everytime when the component is re-rendered. You can place it inside the new hook which I have made in the answer and it will stop repeating. I have updated the answer